# Java process memory is getting increased when i i use HttpURLConnection to check the web server

Tags: memory, httpurlconnection

My requirement is to check if the webserver is listening at some specific port and if not running then i need to start that webservice, So for this i am using below set of code. The below code is working fine but the problem is if i run this code for long time then the java process memory is getting increased from 60MB to 1GB. Please let me know where i am doing wrong.

```
private boolean checkHttpsConnection(String urlString)
{
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.connect();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("some error happened ... ");
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(con != null)
        {
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to call disconnect(), you must close the underlying stream.   disconnect() may, but does not necessarily close the stream.   So:

```
private boolean checkHttpsConnection(String urlString)
{
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.connect();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("some error happened ... ");
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(con != null)
        {
            con.disconnect();
            try
            {
                con.getInputStream().close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {}
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or, even better, use the try-with-resources pattern.

Comment: Thank you BadZen i will try out this once.

Comment: Well, you'll have to fire up a profiler and see exactly what objects aren't being cleared from the heap, then...